# R programming package quantstrat/ FinancialInstrument/ importDefaults loading error

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, quantstrat

I'm trying to install the package `quantstrat`, however I always get following errors trying this:

```
--Error : object ‘importDefaults’ is not exported by 'namespace:quantmod'
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘FinancialInstrument’ could not be loaded’
```

Now, when I tried to load the package `FinancialInstrument`, R throws the following error:

```
--Error : object ‘importDefaults’ is not exported by 'namespace:quantmod'
```

I am not sure what to do to get the package `quantstrat` loaded. I am using the R version `3.0.0` on windows 64 bit system. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the output of `sessionInfo()` into your question. What version of `FinancialInstrument` do you have installed?